# Symfony 4 - in_array with multi array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, symfony4

I've :

```
AdminValidateurController.php on line 43:
array:2 [▼
  0 => Validateur^ {#986 ▼
    -id: 5
    -ordre: 1
    -validateur: User^ {#773 ▶}
  }
  1 => Validateur^ {#988 ▼
    -id: 6
    -ordre: 2
    -validateur: User^ {#1015 ▶}
  }
]
```

A validator contains a User.
I would like to test if a certain User is part of the dump, the Validators board.

For that I have a Validator object, which I can recover the user with $ validateur->getValidateur (). And I want to test if it is already part of validateurs ($ validateurs).

For that, I did:

```
if (in_array($validateur->getValidateur(), $validateurs)) {
    dd("oui");
}
```

But it doesn't work :s

Comment: What are the object types and where do they come from? A database query? `$validateur->getValidateur()` returns `User` and `$validateurs` is the array you posted?

Comment: Yes it's correct. It's a database query, and $validateur->getValidateur() returns User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array comes from a database you can check if the user is a validator using a query. For instance:

```
$exists = $validateurRepository->findOneBy(['validateur' => $validateur->getValidateur());  
// Or find($validateur->getId()) if it's already persisted
if (null != $exists) {
    //...
}
```

But if you already have the result as an array you can remap it to a `User` array and do the checking:

```
$users = array_map(function($e) { return $e->getValidateur(); }, $validateurs);
if (in_array($validateur->getValidateur(), $users)) {
    dd("oui");
}
```

Comment: Yeah ! Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: You're the best :)